# wrap a div around text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to wrap a `<input type="text">` just around text `hello world`. `Span` should not be surrounded by it.

```
<div class="outer">
    "hello world"
    <span class="inner">Inner</span>
</div>

$('.inner').parent().contents().wrap('<input type="text"/>')
```

This one wraps input around both text and span. I want to avoid around span. Can anyone please help me.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzz9f7y4/)

Comment: `<input>` is not allowed to have children. This will result in an invalid HTML.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/4osn1uqp/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't wrap a text field around some content, you need

```js
var el = $('.inner')[0].previousSibling;

$('<input />').val(el.nodeValue.trim()).insertBefore('.inner');
$(el).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  "hello world"
  <span class="inner">Inner</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the inner div in a variable, and then appending it at the end after you replace what is in the outer div. Like this:

```
// Save the inner tag
var inner = document.querySelector(".inner").outerHTML;

// Remove the inner tag
document.querySelector(".inner").parentNode.remove(document.querySelector(".inner"));

// Wrap the text, then add the saved tag. 
document.querySelector(".outer").innerHTML("<input type=\"text\">" 
+ document.querySelector(".outer").innerHTML 
+ "</input>" + inner);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.filter()` , `.replaceWith()`

```js
// return `#text` node having `"hello world"` as `textContent`
var text = $(".inner").parent().contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3 && /hello world/.test(this.textContent)
});
// replace `text` with `input type="text"` element
// having value of `text` `textContent`
text.replaceWith(function() {  
  return "<input type=text value=" + this.textContent + "/>"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="outer">
  "hello world"
  <span class="inner">Inner</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just take the first element from the contents:

```js
$('.inner').parent().contents().first().wrap("<input type='text'/>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
    "hello world"
    <span class="inner">Inner</span>
</div>
```

Result is:

```
<div class="outer">
    <input type="text">hello world</input>
    <span class="inner">Inner</span>
</div>
```

Note that I have provided that only to help you understand how `contents()` method works.
`<input type="text">hello world</input>` is **not a valid HTML**.